# 2 xeon X5650 CPU , but only 6 threads per CPU

Tags: cpu

From [intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/47922/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5650-12M-Cache-2_66-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI) it says each CPU has 6 cores and 12 threads. I have 2 CPUs, so this should give me 12 cores and 24 threads.

I can see there are 2 CPUs, but only 12 threads.

I am using Windows 10 Pro, with Hyper-V on.

Is this a problem of hardware or software?

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Windows 10 is simply configured to only display a single cpu by default](http://www.windows10forums.com/threads/multi-cpu-support.367/)

Comment: @DoctorLai: Have you checked the BIOS to see if Hyperthreading is enabled? This is what gives two threads per core.

Comment: In the screenshot of CPU-Z you clearly have only Processor #2 selected."  [This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/single-processor-issue-on-dual-processor-machine/b470a855-b580-41f6-b5b2-c9720a6433ca?auth=1) thread has a command you should that.  Plus [WMI](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1ed7b15-485c-4c97-9cd1-f7104c369c0d/how-to-find-if-hyperthreading-is-enabled-using-wmi?forum=csharplanguage) to determine if HT is turned on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, tried James' suggestions.

Turning on Hyperthreading in Bios is the way to go.

https://helloacm.com/review-hpz800-server-workstation-hp-z800-workstation-desktop-pc-tower-computer-powerhouse-2x-intel-xeon-x5650-48gb-ddr3-memory-2tb-hdd-1gb-nvidia-quadro/

[image]